# MySQL reusable results as table with parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, table

I used to use MySQL but nothing more complicated than `JOIN`s, then I worked for a year at a company that uses MSSQL, where I learnt how to program stored procedures. My current company uses MySQL.

In MSSQL, you can use the result of a stored procedure as a table in a query, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t
JOIN Proc(NOW()) p
  ON p.value = t.value
```

I've been trying to do the same thing in MySQL, but so far to no avail. MySQL doesn't let you use the result of a stored procedure in a query, and views don't take parameters, nor are they programmable.

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html) says that stored functions only return scalar values, so that's out too.

Is there a way to get the same effect in MySQL?

I think one way might be to create a temporary table in the stored procedure. Call the stored procedure before running the query, then `JOIN` to the temporary table.

Comment: yes, temporary table is possible way

Comment: No such syntax.  If you would like to show us the proc, maybe we could suggest another way to code _that_ use.